# Adwords script create shopping campaign

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm trying to create new google shopping campaigns through an adwords script. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257078/how-to-create-new-campaign-using-adwords-script) which works perfectly. Except when you make it a shopping campaign it does not.

According to [this article](https://support.google.com/adwords/editor/answer/6332885?hl=en) you have to add more columns which makes sense so I did. But running the script creates a failed bulk upload with error "Unable to determine the entity-type of this row. Make sure that you only provide fields for columns that are appropriate for the entity."

Does anyone know why google cannot determine what I'm trying to do?

The code I created:

```
function main()
{
    var columns = [
        'Campaign',
        'Campaign Type',
        'Budget Name',
        'Budget',
        'Bid Strategy type',

        'Country of Sale',
        'Ad Group',
        'Max CPC',
        'Product Group',
        'Product Group Type',
        'Merchant',
    ];

    var upload = AdWordsApp.bulkUploads().newCsvUpload(
        columns, {moneyInMicros: false});

    // AdWords identify existing campaigns using its name. To create a new
    // campaign, use a campaign name that doesn't exist in your account.
    upload.append({
        'Campaign': 'Shopping - 100',
        'Campaign Type': 'Shopping',
        'Budget Name': 'Shopping',
        'Budget': 500,
        'Bid Strategy type': 'cpc',

        'Country of Sale': 'NL',
        'Ad Group': 'Shopping - 100',
        'Max CPC': 0.10,
        'Product Group': '* / custom label 0 = *',
        'Product Group Type': 'Biddable',
        'Merchant': 1234,
    });
    // Use upload.apply() to make changes without previewing.
    upload.preview();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a comma behind 'Merchant': 1234 - tried to remove it?

Also it seems that the entities you use are not the ones provided by google for the bulk-upload of shopping campains: [Download here](https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/xsPnU2iMcfgJfrQI70Vf0eGfbK8lpSCJFDlL)

I'm in preparation for the same task in the coming two weeks - maybe I can provide more information after.

You definitely have to use AdWords Editor - the Bulk_Upload cannot create Shopping Campaigns

Answer (score 0):

AdScript currently does not allow Shopping campaigns to be created.

Create a file for AdsEditor instead.